# How to add Web Animations API polyfill to an Angular 2 project created with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

The [Angular 2 animations documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) refers to the [Web Animations API polyfill](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js) for browsers that don't support the native one.

**What's the *proper* way to add this polyfill to an Angular 2 project created with Angular CLI?**

(I am using angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.10)

With no luck, I have tried the ideas and solutions mentioned here:

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/949
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1015
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/718#issuecomment-225493863

I downloaded it via NPM and added it to `system-config.ts`. I believe this is along the lines of what's *recommended* but the polyfill doesn't get loaded (I can tell because the animations don't work in Safari).

I only got this to work by including the polyfill in `index.html`, which I know it's not the proper way:

```
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/web-animations/web-animations-js/master/web-animations.min.js"></script>
```

I will add here any details that may help clarify my question, but if you need to see the code, I have it on Github:

https://github.com/cmermingas/connect-four

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No longer required for Angular 6 and later :-) https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Angular 6 Note - Polyfill no longer required :-)

> **Animations Performance Improvements**
>
> We’ve updated our implementation
> of Animations to no longer need the web animations polyfill. This
> means that you can remove this polyfill from your application and save
> approximately 47KB of bundle size, while increasing animations
> performance in Safari at the same time.

:-)

https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4

Comment: Note: As far as I can tell the `ng update` logic doesn't currently remove this so you have to uninstall it yourself.

Comment: Then why doesn't the animation function equivalent to Chrome on Safari?

Comment: @LoveenDyall can you clarify what you mean. Is the animation not working on Safari or behaving differently? Or do you mean why did it ORIGINALLY not work - in which case it's probably just something to do with standards not having been implemented - but I don't really keep up with that and only do very basic animations.

Answer (score 40):

Adding the polyfill with the newer, Webpack version of Angular CLI is easier:

1. Install with `npm install web-animations-js --save`
2. Add to `polyfills.ts`: `require('web-animations-js/web-animations.min');`

It also worked if I do `import 'web-animations-js/web-animations.min';`

Comment: I tried this in polyfills.ts for `require('smoothscroll-polyfill').polyfill();`, but I keep getting an error saying `D:/Projects/app/src/polyfills.ts (70,1): Cannot find name 'require'.`.  Any idea how I might include this polyfill?

Comment: @mtpultz Currently, the polyfill.ts script has a commented out line with the proper import.

Comment: This solution is currently not working for an angular 2 project.

Comment: Safal: I haven't had a chance to revisit this with a newer version of Angular and the CLI. Have you tried looking at the comments in polyfill.ts that Trenton and others have mentioned?

Comment: @CarlosMermingas Yes. I have imported 'web-animations-js/web-animations.min' inside polyfills.ts as mentioned in the answer. Still the animations are choppy in firefox. I have opened a new query about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45210966/choppy-angular-2-animations-in-firefox-intergrating-web-animations-js-in-angula).

Comment: Just tried to replicate the issue in angular 4 with latest cli version with the same answer. Animation issue still persists. Is there any other step I'm missing?

Comment: @Safal my polyfill.ts generated by angular cli 1.2.6  contains this line:`// import 'web-animations-js'; ` So you need to replace require by import as mentioned by @Trenton

Comment: @CarlosMermingas I am using webpack version of angular cli and I get SCRIPT5007: Object expected; web-animations.min.js (15,23868) error in IE9. Followed same steps.

Answer (score 9):

In Angular 4 simply follow the below steps :

1. add web-animations-js as a dependency :

   npm install web-animations-js
2. And uncomment the following line in `polyfils.ts`

   import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

Comment: Dezza, I am using webpack version of angular cli/ angular4 and I get SCRIPT5007: Object expected; web-animations.min.js (15,23868) error in IE9. Followed same steps.

Comment: Not sure to be honest. Maybe try delete node_modules, 'npm cache clean --force', 'npm install' to reset everything

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have already done the most steps. Just to make it complete:

1) run npm install web-animations-js --save

2) add *web-animation-js* to *angular-cli-build.js* to make clear it is a vendor package:

```
return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
       ...
      'web-animations-js/**/*'
    ]
});
```

3) Configure system-js (system-config.ts)

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'web-animations-js': 'vendor/web-animations-js'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'web-animations-js': {main: 'web-animations.min.js'}
};
```

The main point here is that we need to tell system-js what the main file of this package is. System-js is not able to get this information from the *package.json* file - system-js expects the file is *index.js*. But it is not. It is *web-animations.min.js*.

4) In your *main.ts* file add:

```
import 'web-animations-js';
```

5) Stop and restart all processes that are using the angular-cli-build.js (ng server, ng test, etc).

Now system js will load the *web-animation.js* polyfill.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I made the changes and I get a 404 error in the browser: `GET http://localhost:4200/vendor/web-animation-js/web-animations.min.js 404 (Not Found)
Unhandled Promise rejection: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/vendor/web-animation-js/web-animations.min.js ...` - There's a `vendor` directory in the project but `web-animations-js` is not in it (it's only in `node_modules`).

Comment: are you really sure you have done step 2? This makes sure that in your dist/vendor folder the web-animations folder is present. Also: you need to stop and start all processes that are using the angular-cli-build.js - ng server, ng test, ...

Comment: Stopping and restarting the processes did the trick. Thank you very much!

Comment: i don't find the angulr-cli-build.js file, i have only the angular-cli.ts, where do i find it? If it is the same file, where do i have to add the vendorNpnFiles array?

Comment: @mautrok I think this accepted answer is a little out of date as Angular-cli now uses webpack not system.js for builds.

As below, you need to use npm to install it as a dependency and then import it into polyfills.ts

That works a fine for me in real browsers, but currently causes errors using PhantomJS

Answer (score 2):

I just did this with Visual Studio + gulp.

1. Add this line to packages.json:

   `"web-animations-js": "^2.2.2"`

This will make sure that the package is downloaded to node_modules folder.

2. Add this line to gulpfile.js in the gulp.src array:

   `'web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js'`

This will make sure that the file is copied into libs folder (or whatever you specified) during every gulp build.

3. And this is how you import it in TypeScript:

   `import 'libs/web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js';`

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these 3 steps:

**1- Run this command:** npm i -D web-animations-js

**2- Add these lines of codes to the "angular.json" file.**

```
{
...
"projects:" {
  ...
  "architect": {
    ....
    "build": {
      ...
      "scripts": [
              {
                "input": "node_modules/web-animations-js/web-animations.min.js",
                "inject": false,
                "bundleName": "web-animations-js"
              }
            ],
```

**Third, add these lines of codes to the "ployfills.ts" file.**

```
if (!('animate' in document.documentElement) || (navigator && /iPhone OS (8|9|10|11|12|13)_/.test(navigator.userAgent))) {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'web-animations-js.js';
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Note that I've surrounded the code in an **if** statement because this code will make an issue on old iOS devices usually in iPhone 6 with iOS 12