# Angular 4 Animations don't work on iOS Safari 10/11

Tags: ios, angular, animation, mobile-safari

I've seen a lot of people around here talking about Angular animations. Well, no solutions is working for me. I'm currently using Angular 4, with angular-cli v1.1.1. I'm using Angular animation on several steps of my applications, in my router-outlet too. Turns out in Safari 10/11 ( mobile ) no animations is currently working. 
In my `polyfills.ts` I have the following line of code `import 'web-animations-js';` which should work on every browser that doesn't fully support Angular animations. On IE 10/11 it's working, not perfectly but it's working. Firefox too. 
The real problem on mobile Safari 10/11 is the `animate` syntax. With this particular syntax any animation wouldn't work. my `router-outlet` doesn't even show.

I can't understand why this doesn't work, any clue?
Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

`initial: style({ transform: 'translateY(100vh)' }),
  animate: animate(
    ${phaseDuration}ms ${phaseDuration}ms ease-in,
    style({ transform: 'translateY(0)' })
  )
};`

This is the code that breaks everything, inside che enter transition

Comment: I'm guessing you did `npm install` the animations polyfill, right?

Comment: @OsmanCea Yes, I did. I'm not using the last version of Angular ( using the 4.0.0 for some business requirement ). and web-animation-js v.2.3.1

Comment: I had the same issue. Follow this link. It would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71557862/6666348

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the polyfill library has several open issues with the integration with mobile Safari. 
However, if the iPhone or iPad requests for Desktop Site the animations work fine.

Comment: I've had problems with keyframes with iOS even in latest Angular. Very erratic, but when doing simpler animations from state to state it was ok