# Angular NPM Package With Material Design Components

Tags: angular, npm, gulp, angular-material

I'm developing an Angular 5 NPM package library for use in applications.  Unfortunately, this is one area of Angular development that appears to be very poorly (un)documented, so it's been a lot of trial and error.

I've developed a test application that consumes the NPM package and uses its components.  At this point, it's working perfectly except when running production compiled code.

My NPM package utilizes a lot of Angular Material components.  Once compiled, the browser throws 'Object doesn't support this action' every time my code tries to display an Angular Material dialog (from the library).  Interestingly though, a component that exists IN the library can launch a dialog using the exact same method.  The problem only exists with launching a dialog in the library from my consuming application.

I'm guessing that the solution lies somewhere in the realm of polyfills.  But I'm not sure where/how to implement them in my NPM package, if indeed that is the issue.  Implementing them on the application that consumes the package does not resolve the issue.  I've tried adding polyfill import statements into the index.ts file of my NPM package - but that didn't help either.

The structure of the NPM package and the way that it's compiled is somewhat foreign to me.  It's not like a "standard" Angular app built and compiled via the CLI.  It uses gulp, which is new to me and is rather troublesome (I often have to tell it to build 5 times in a row to get it to work).

**I used the following project as a starting point for my NPM package:**
https://github.com/qurt/generator-angular4-library

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41528268/3055401) may help with the pollyfills and gulp

Comment: I've just discovered that the code also fails in development mode if I use the --aot flag.  So the problem may not be a pollyfill issue?  It seems that it may be more related to aot.  Is it possible that my NPM library isn't aot-compliant?

Comment: Its very possible, [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/edit) is the currently recommended format. I guess you could compare yours to what is recommended. [here](https://github.com/jasonaden/simple-ui-lib) is a more recent package seed if you are prepared to port it over.

Comment: And I've further discovered that the only dialogs that seem to be throwing an error and not working are ones that I pass data to.  If I just launch a dialog without passing data to it, it works.

Comment: @Und3rTow, thanks for the document!  I'm reviewing it to see if I can bring my project into compliance with that standard.