# web-animations-js giving error in IE 9 SCRIPT5007: Object expected; web-animations.min.js (15,23868)

Tags: angular, web-animations

I am using angular 5.

Followed following steps:

add web-animations-js as a dependency :

```
npm install web-animations-js
```

And uncomment the following line in polyfils.ts

```
import 'web-animations-js'; // Run npm install --save web-animations-js.
```

polyfill.ts:

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
 import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
 import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

I am getting error in IE9, working fine in chrome, firefox and IE10 and 11:

> SCRIPT5007: Object expected
>
> web-animations.min.js (15,23868)

[image: error in IE9]

Referred: [Adding the polyfill with the newer, Webpack version of Angular CLI is easier:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836532/how-to-add-web-animations-api-polyfill-to-an-angular-2-project-created-with-angu#answer-39778524)

Also, I have added polyfill for promise lib in index.html as promise is not supported in IE9:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you found any solution? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It can be fixed by commenting out this line in `polyfill.ts`:

```
//import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

But the next issues after fixing the above issue will be:

1. Animation will not work in IE 10, 11
2. And the following error will be outputted in console of IE:

   > The provided animation property "transform" is not a supported CSS property for animations

And this animation property will not work in IE 9 because Angular Material supports the most recent two versions of all major browsers: Chrome (including Android), Firefox, Safari (including iOS), and IE11 / Edge
https://github.com/angular/material2#browser-and-screen-reader-support

The issue is closed - [as we still have not be able to reproduce this issue on a supported browser.](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11044)

So it can work just in IE 10, 11